# How to persist and display selected items in multi_select_flutter widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I'm working with this library: https://pub.dev/packages/multi_select_flutter.

Expected behavior:

1. Selected items are saved to the DB.
2. Selected items are displayed below the MultiSelectDialogField  (are these chips?) after form save (rebuild).
3. Selected items display checked when the dialog is reopened.

Actual behavior:

1. Selected items are saved to the DB.
2. Selected items are NOT displayed below the MultiSelectDialogField  (are these chips?) after form save (rebuild).
3. Selected items DO NOT display as checked when the dialog is reopened.

I have tried this as both a Stateless and a Stateful widget. No difference in behavior. I'm posting the Stateful version since that is the most recent version I have.

I'm pulling data from Firestore as a stream, so I'm wrapping the MultiSelectDialogField in a StreamBuilder.

I have read and tried solutions related to the following:

1. https://github.com/CHB61/multi_select_flutter/issues/5
2. https://github.com/CHB61/multi_select_flutter/issues/12
3. [I want to use multi_select_flutter package, and didn't understand what to pass in MultiSelectItem" arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71477257/i-want-to-use-multi-select-flutter-package-and-didnt-understand-what-to-pass-i)
4. [how to get selections from multi_select_flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67143656/how-to-get-selections-from-multi-select-flutter)

This is my wrapper (MultiSelectField):

```
class MultiSelectField<V extends LookupItem> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Stream<List<V>> stream;
  final List<V> initialValue;
  final FormFieldSetter<List<V>> onConfirm;

  const MultiSelectField({
    Key key,
    @required this.stream,
    @required this.initialValue,
    @required this.onConfirm,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MultiSelectFieldState createState() => _MultiSelectFieldState<V>();
}

class _MultiSelectFieldState<V extends LookupItem>
    extends State<MultiSelectField<V>> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: widget.stream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<V>> snapshot) {
          return MultiSelectDialogField(
              buttonText: Text('Select Lease Types'),
              title: Text('Select all that apply'),
              items: snapshot.data
                  .map((item) => MultiSelectItem(item, item.name))
                  .toList(),
              initialValue: widget.initialValue,
              onConfirm: widget.onConfirm);
        });
  }
}
```

This is my usage:

```
  Widget _buildLeaseList(BuildContext context, Case c) {
    return MultiSelectField(
        initialValue: c.leases,
        stream: Provider.of<Repository>(context).getLeaseTypes(),
        onConfirm: (result) {
          var leaseTypes = _castToLeaseType(result);
          c.leases = leaseTypes;
        });
  }

  List<LeaseType> _castToLeaseType(List<LeaseType> leases) {
    return leases.map((e) => e).toList();
  }
```

Please let me know if there is any further information that would be helpful.

Thank you!!!

Comment: So the selected items are shown as chips after you confirm the selection, but disappear after you save them to the DB?
Also, what do you exactly mean by save(rebuild)? What is rebuilt?

Comment: @Csisanyi, yes. Chips for selected items are shown after confirmation, but once the form is saved, they disappear. The items are being save to the DB, but I can't figure out how to get them to show up when the widget is rebuilt. The form is rebuilt after being saved because state is updated. I may not be using the term correctly & welcome any corrections! :) Thank you